# What are the pros/cons of preferring sending the latest commitment or the oldest commitment?

Tags: lightning-network

Roasbeef [mentioned](http://www.erisian.com.au/meetbot/lightning-dev/2019/lightning-dev.2019-08-05-20.03.log.html#l-257) on IRC that the Lightning specification allows a client to either assume that the latest co-signed commitment has been received by the counterparty, or that it hasn't. (as far as I understand that linked discussion. If I got it wrong, please edit the question)

For an implementation, what are the consequences of preferring to send the oldest co-signed, or sending the newest co-signed? (both unrevoked)

Comment: Can you please clarify further what you mean by "preferring to send the oldest co-signed, or sending the newest co-signed?". I'll update my answer after that.

Comment: When you receive `commitment_signed`, you have the signature for a new commitment transaction. But you havn't revoked the old one yet, so it will still be valid. Therefore, you will have two co-signed commitment transactions. One is older than the other. The counterparty cannot know if you received `commitment_signed` unless you acknowledge it. So if you reconnect and send `channel_reestablish` you can choose the value of `next_commitment_number`. If you send a low value, the counterparty might conclude that you lost data, in which case it could breach the channel without fear of repercussion.